# how do I edit a previous edit that hasn't been accepted yet?

Tags: support

I submitted an edit (cleaned up some grammar) on one of the posts. After doing so, I realized that I'd also inadvertently changed a technical term to something with possibly-different meaning. I'd like to fix up my edit, but it is currently sitting in some queue waiting to be accepted, before it gets applied. Is there any way to access my own edits that are sitting in the submission queue?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember on SO, when you have the ability to edit without peer review, you can change other peoples' edits with the improve option. As for your own edits, I was under the impression that your edits will appear for you (and only you until they're approved) which should allow you to simply edit the post. I believe it will overwrite what is in the queue.

I don't see a submission queue available to me (despite the faq saying I have enough rep to approve/reject edits), but if you link the question I should be able to see what edits you've made and I can tell you if it updated. :)

Comment: I edited this post: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/239/which-locator-do-you-use-with-selenium-css-or-xpath - but I changed the term 'locator' to 'selector engine', but after submitting I double-checked and found that 'locator' is actually a technical term for Selenium. When I click 'edit' now, I see the original  text, not my edits.

Comment: @Bruce it doesn't seem to show you having any edits in the queue. Try making the edits again and update here and I'll see if they show up.

Comment: ok, I edited it again; thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I checked a few times, it never showed up to approve/reject. Strange. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Weird -- I checked and we have absolutely zero record of this edit, as an edit suggestion or as a regular edit.

How soon after the question was asked did you edit it?

What happened after you saved the edit?

Can you try again?

Comment: Well, leave it to the SQA forum to find the bugs, right? :-)

Comment: I just tried it again - this time it worked as expected.  I did change one variable this time: I use the 'noscript' plugin for Firefox, but I did already have (what I thought was) the necessary scripts enabled for the site.  For this most recent attempt, however, I enabled *all* scripting - specifically 'google-analytics.com' and 'quantserve.com', which had previously been disabled.  I don't know why that would make a difference, but perhaps it will mean something for you.

Comment: glowcoder is exactly right, btw - I started using noscript specifically to help me test the behavior of my own product.  I'd seen some weird errors a while back that I suspected were due to the use of script/ad blockers.